# HTML/CSS Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I have a html page which takes hour and minute inputs for exams.
- In another html or css document I would like to essentially run a countdown timer of HH:MM. i.e. if input was 1 hour and 10 min it would countdown from 01:10 to 00:00. I am assuming there is some way of calling the input values from one module to another.
- I would also like to make this countdown start when a start button is pressed
- The display module (Exam Display) is split into 4 quarters such that 4 exam timers can run concurrently. (I am hoping that in the case that there is no input value, when the start button is pressed nothing will happen with that particular timer)

I am attaching both jsfiddle and the code.
For ExamSetup.html & ExamSetup.css
-https://jsfiddle.net/vf113tux/1/
OR
ExamSetup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ExamSetup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="Exam 1">
<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Exam 1</legend>

        <label for="Exam Name">Name</label>
        <input id="Name1" type="text" placeholder="Name">

        <label for="Exam Writing Time">Writing Time</label>
        <input id="Writing1H" type="number" placeholder="Hours" min="0" max="12">
        <input id="Writing1M" type="number" placeholder="Minutes" min="0" max="60">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<div id="Exam 2">
<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
    <fieldset>
         <legend>Exam 2</legend>

        <label for="Exam Name">Name</label>
        <input id="Name2" type="text" placeholder="Name"

        <label for="Exam Writing Time">Writing Time</label>
        <input id="Writing2H" type="number" placeholder="Hours" min="0" max="12">
        <input id="Writing2M" type="number" placeholder="Minutes" min="0" max="60">
    </fieldset>
</form>

</div>

<div id="Exam 3">
<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Exam 3</legend>

        <label for="Exam Name">Name</label>
        <input id="Name3" type="text" placeholder="Name">

        <label for="Exam Writing Time">Writing Time</label>
        <input id="Writing3H" type="number" placeholder="Hours" min="0" max="12">
        <input id="Writing3M" type="number" placeholder="Minutes" min="0" max="60">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<div id="Exam 4">
<form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">  
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Exam 4</legend>

        <label for="Exam Name">Name</label>
        <input id="Name4" type="text" placeholder="Name">

        <label for="Exam Writing Time">Writing Time</label>
        <input id="Writing4H" type="number" placeholder="Hours" min="0" max="12">
        <input id="Writing4M" type="number" placeholder="Minutes" min="0" max="60">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div class ="span7 text-center">
<a href="Display.html"><button type="submit" button id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Next</button>
</div>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

ExamSetup.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div { width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left; }

button {
    text-align: center;
}
```

For ExamDisplay.html & ExamDisplay.css
- https://jsfiddle.net/890e2dmq/ (Note for backgrounds are there simply to show the quarter partitions)
OR
ExamDisplay.html:
    
    
    
        
        Untitled Document

```
<body>

<div id="div1">
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
<div id="div3">
</div>
<div id="div4">
</div>

<button id="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

ExamDisplay.css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body { height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
div { width: 50%; height: 50%; float: left; }
#div1 { background: #DDD; }
#div2 { background: #AAA; }
#div3 { background: #777; }
#div4 { background: #444; }
```

Thank you very much! And I have checked through quite extensively for the last day but have found it rather difficult to find a proper simple countdown that I require. Many of the developed programs out are mainly for dates or they are for DD:HH:MM:SS and I was unable to edit the code to incorporate only HH:MM.

Comment: Have you attempted a JavaScript version of this by yourself? Show us what you have tried!

Comment: @codyogden, I have attempted using this: https://github.com/Reflejo/jquery-countdown. But was unable to edit the codes there for my requirement

Comment: As far as I know you can't create a timer etc with HTML and CSS only because neither of them are actual programing/script languages. You would need to use javascript for this project. If you choose to use JS I would help you with the code (if you with to)

Comment: @ThermalCube that would be great! How would I go about writing some JS for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now the improoved version with 4 timers (CSS is up to you).
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ThermalCube/yb9ht0np/) (full version)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function start1(){
        var h1 = $('input:text[name=h1]').val();
        var m1 = $('input:text[name=m1]').val();
        $('.counter1').html(h1+' : '+m1);
        var inter1 = setInterval(function(){
            m1--;
            if(m1 == 0 && h1 != 0){
                m1 = 59;
                h1--;
            }else{
                if(h1 == 0 && m1 == 0){
                    clearInterval(inter1);
                }
            }
            $('.counter1').html(h1+' : '+m1);
            
        },60000)
    }
  
  $('#sub1').click(function(){
    start1();
  })
});
```

```css
body{
    position: relative;
}
.counter1{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    left: 0%;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src ="yourPathToYourJavascript.js"></script>

<div class="counter1"></div>

<input type="text" name="h1" value="Hours"></input><br>
<input type="text" name="m1" value="Minutes"></input><br>
<input type="submit" id="sub1" value="Couter #1"></input><br>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Just a few questions
1. How do I call an input from a different module?
2. As you can see from my uploaded ExamDisplay.html/css, the screen is partitioned into 4 quarters. How would I fit the code you gave me into each partition? i.e. Have 4 concurrent timers running

Comment: I've one more question. Let's say I wanted to add :SS. i..e it now shows HH:MM:SS but only takes HH:MM input. How would I do that?

Comment: @Vish you would need to add a new input, edit the if() part and reduce the interval ( from 60000ms to 1000ms ). In addition to that you would have to add your seconds to $('.counter').html()

Comment: @Vish so about 10 lines more per counter